# Wordpress additional info

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

That's what my post looks like at the moment:

[image]

I have the title ( David Art ) and the content (image + 1.25 eth). I as well have featured image:
[image]

When I'm trying to get the title and featured image it works ok. But there are problems with content since I`m only able to get it together using `the_content();`. Is there a way to grab text "1.25 eth" and this small image separately?

Comment: Here's a quick guide to using custom meta fields - which would solve your problem by adding the `eth` text and small image fields for your page: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to create a "custom post type" (instead of a regular port) and save those bits of content in different fields which you create in the custom post type. The content of these fields can then be called separately from a php template.

BTW: It's not necessary to create a custom post type from scratch in your functions.php – you can also use the PODS plugin to create them which is a lot easier.

Comment: The OP could also just use custom meta fields on a default page/post as well. No need to create custom post types or install any plugin.